# Line Break <br/> tag is not rendering from Java Servlet code

Tags: java, html, servlets

I created a basic 'dynamic webapp' using servlet. Created a form in index.html page, which calls the servlet's doGet method. Below is my code for doGetMethod.

```
String firstName = request.getParameter("fname");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print("Hello World! doGet Method");
    out.print("<br/> Hello " + firstName);
```

Giving first Name as John, this is my output

```
Hello World! doGet Method<br/> Hello John
```

Where as it should have displayed

```
Hello World! doGet Method
Hello John
```

Line break tag is not rendered. Any suggestions to make it work as it should?

Comment: Your code result true, so  Hello John write new line ! Why you are get problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add [this](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentType-java.lang.String-) line of code:

```
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8"); // or whatever encoding you are using
```

before this line of code:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
```

so your code becomes this:

```
String firstName = request.getParameter("fname");
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8"); 
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.print("Hello World! doGet Method");
out.print("<br/> Hello " + firstName);
```

Comment: This worked for me! Although the tutorial I was following didn't 'setContentType', but it still worked. Wonder why?

Comment: @NaveenKumarNarsupalli: tutorials are written by people, and people can make mistakes or forget things